# How to deal with the "Bad file descriptor" caused by select() in socket server?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, select

I compile my program using

```
all:
    gcc server.c -o server
    gcc file_reader.c -o file_reader
```

After compiling, I input "./server [port_num]" in the terminal.

After initializing the server, I can type something on the browser like this: "http://127.0.0.1:[port_num]/cgi_program?filename=[filename]"

Then my CGI(file_reader) will correctly dump the content of the file named "filename" to the browser I type.

I post all of my code here, sorry it's very long since there is a lot of functions to call, you can skip and assume the followings functions are right.

The problem remains the same: an error message "select: Bad file descriptor", and can only read from one guy.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define TIMEOUT_SEC 5       // timeout in seconds for wait for a connection
#define MAXBUFSIZE  1024    // timeout in seconds for wait for a connection
#define NO_USE      0       // status of a http request
#define ERROR       -1
#define READING     1
#define WRITING     2
#define ERR_EXIT(a) { perror(a); exit(1); }

typedef struct {
    char hostname[512];     // hostname
    unsigned short port;    // port to listen
    int listen_fd;          // fd to wait for a new connection
} http_server;

typedef struct {
    int conn_fd;               // fd to talk with client
    int status;                // not used, error, reading (from client), writing (to client)

    char file[MAXBUFSIZE];     // requested file
    char query[MAXBUFSIZE];    // requested query
    char host[MAXBUFSIZE];     // client host
    char* buf;                 // data sent by/to client
    size_t buf_len;            // bytes used by buf
    size_t buf_size;           // bytes allocated for buf
    size_t buf_idx;            // offset for reading and writing
} http_request;

static char* logfilenameP;  // log file name

static void init_http_server(http_server *svrP, unsigned short port);   // initailize a http_request instance, exit for error
static void init_request(http_request* reqP);                           // initailize a http_request instance
static void free_request(http_request* reqP);                           // free resources used by a http_request instance
static int read_header_and_file(http_request* reqP, int *errP);
// return 0: success, file is buffered in retP->buf with retP->buf_len bytes
// return -1: error, check error code (*errP)
// return 1: continue to it until return -1 or 0
// error code:
// 1: client connection error
// 2: bad request, cannot parse request
// 3: method not implemented
// 4: illegal filename
// 5: illegal query
// 6: file not found
// 7: file is protected

static void set_ndelay(int fd);
// Set NDELAY mode on a socket.

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    http_server server;            // http server
    http_request* requestP = NULL; // pointer to http requests from client

    int maxfd;                     // size of open file descriptor table

    struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;    // used by accept()
    int clilen;

    int conn_fd;        // fd for a new connection with client
    int err;            // used by read_header_and_file()
    int i, ret, nwritten;

    // Initialize http server
    init_http_server(&server, (unsigned short) atoi(argv[1]));

    maxfd = getdtablesize();
    requestP = (http_request*) malloc(sizeof(http_request) * maxfd);
    if (requestP == (http_request*) 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory allocating all http requests\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < maxfd; i ++)
        init_request(&requestP[i]);
    requestP[server.listen_fd].conn_fd = server.listen_fd;
    requestP[server.listen_fd].status = READING;

    fprintf(stderr, "\nstarting on %.80s, port %d, fd %d, maxconn %d, logfile %s...\n", server.hostname, server.port, server.listen_fd, maxfd, logfilenameP);

    fd_set master;          /* master file descriptor list */
    fd_set read_fds;        /* temp file descriptor list for select() */
    FD_SET(server.listen_fd, &master);

    int fdmax = server.listen_fd;
    while (1) {                             /* Main loop */
        read_fds = master;

        if (select(fdmax + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1)
            ERR_EXIT("select")
            printf("server select() is OK!\n");

        for (i = 0; i < fdmax + 1; i++) {
            if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)) {
                if (i == server.listen_fd) {
                    clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
                    conn_fd = accept(server.listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, (socklen_t *) &clilen);
                    if (conn_fd < 0) {
                        if (errno == EINTR || errno == EAGAIN) continue; // try again
                        if (errno == ENFILE) {
                            (void) fprintf(stderr, "out of file descriptor table ... (maxconn %d)\n", maxfd);
                            continue;
                        }
                        ERR_EXIT("accept")
                    }
                    requestP[conn_fd].conn_fd = conn_fd;
                    requestP[conn_fd].status = READING;
                    strcpy(requestP[conn_fd].host, inet_ntoa(cliaddr.sin_addr));
                    set_ndelay(conn_fd);
                    FD_SET(conn_fd, &master);
                    if (conn_fd > fdmax)
                        fdmax = conn_fd;
                    fprintf(stderr, "getting a new request... fd %d from %s\n", conn_fd, requestP[conn_fd].host);
                }
                else {      /* Handle data from a client */
                    ret = read_header_and_file(&requestP[i], &err);
                    if (ret == 1) continue;
                    else if (ret < 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "error on fd %d, code %d\n", requestP[i].conn_fd, err);
                        requestP[i].status = ERROR;
                        close(requestP[i].conn_fd);
                        free_request(&requestP[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (ret == 0) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "writing (buf %s, idx %d) %d bytes to request fd %d\n", requestP[conn_fd].buf, (int) requestP[conn_fd].buf_idx, (int) requestP[conn_fd].buf_len, requestP[conn_fd].conn_fd);
                        nwritten = write(requestP[conn_fd].conn_fd, requestP[conn_fd].buf, requestP[conn_fd].buf_len);
                        fprintf(stderr, "complete writing %d bytes on fd %d\n", nwritten, requestP[conn_fd].conn_fd);
                        fprintf(stderr, "=============================================\n");

                        // char *m = strchr(requestP[conn_fd].query, '=') + 1;
                        // char *filename = strncpy(requestP[conn_fd].query, m, sizeof(requestP[conn_fd].query));

                        int fd[2];
                        if (pipe(fd) == -1)
                            ERR_EXIT("pipe")

                            pid_t pid;
                        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
                            ERR_EXIT("fork")
                        }
                        else if (pid == 0) {       /* In Child Process */
                            close(fd[0]);
                            dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                            close(fd[1]);

                            execl("file_reader", "./file_reader", requestP[i].query, (char *)0);
                            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unexpect flow of control.\n");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
                        else {      /* In Parent Process */
                            close(fd[1]);
                            char recv[1024];
                            read(fd[0], recv, sizeof(recv));
                            printf("The file content is:\n%s\n", recv);
                        }
                        close(conn_fd);              // I forgot to close the listen conn_fd!
                        free_request(&requestP[i]);
                        FD_CLR(conn_fd, &master);    // I forgot to FD_CLR the conn_fd!
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    free(requestP);
    return 0;
}
//=========================
//The following are some APIs

#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

static void add_to_buf(http_request *reqP, char* str, size_t len);
static void strdecode(char* to, char* from);
static int hexit(char c);
static char* get_request_line(http_request *reqP);
static void* e_malloc(size_t size);
static void* e_realloc(void* optr, size_t size);

static void init_request(http_request* reqP) {
    reqP->conn_fd = -1;
    reqP->status = 0;       // not used
    reqP->file[0] = (char) 0;
    reqP->query[0] = (char) 0;
    reqP->host[0] = (char) 0;
    reqP->buf = NULL;
    reqP->buf_size = 0;
    reqP->buf_len = 0;
    reqP->buf_idx = 0;
}

static void free_request(http_request* reqP) {
    if (reqP->buf != NULL) {
        free(reqP->buf);
        reqP->buf = NULL;
    }
    init_request(reqP);
}


#define ERR_RET(error) { *errP = error; return -1; }
// return 0: success, file is buffered in retP->buf with retP->buf_len bytes
// return -1: error, check error code (*errP)
// return 1: read more, continue until return -1 or 0
// error code:
// 1: client connection error
// 2: bad request, cannot parse request
// 3: method not implemented
// 4: illegal filename
// 5: illegal query
// 6: file not found
// 7: file is protected
//
static int read_header_and_file(http_request* reqP, int *errP) {
    // Request variables
    char* file = (char *) 0;
    char* path = (char *) 0;
    char* query = (char *) 0;
    char* protocol = (char *) 0;
    char* method_str = (char *) 0;
    int r, fd;
    struct stat sb;
    char timebuf[100];
    int buflen;
    char buf[10000];
    time_t now;
    void *ptr;

    // Read in request from client
    while (1) {
        r = read(reqP->conn_fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
        if (r < 0 && (errno == EINTR || errno == EAGAIN)) return 1;
        if (r <= 0) ERR_RET(1)
            add_to_buf(reqP, buf, r);
        if (strstr(reqP->buf, "\015\012\015\012") != (char*) 0 ||
            strstr(reqP->buf, "\012\012") != (char*) 0) break;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "=============================================\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "header: %s", reqP->buf);
    fprintf(stderr, "=============================================\n");

    // Parse the first line of the request.
    method_str = get_request_line(reqP);
    if (method_str == (char*) 0) ERR_RET(2)
        path = strpbrk(method_str, " \t\012\015");
    if (path == (char*) 0) ERR_RET(2)
        *path++ = '\0';
    path += strspn(path, " \t\012\015");
    protocol = strpbrk(path, " \t\012\015");
    if (protocol == (char*) 0) ERR_RET(2)
        *protocol++ = '\0';
    protocol += strspn(protocol, " \t\012\015");
    query = strchr(path, '?');
    if (query == (char*) 0)
        query = "";
    else
        *query++ = '\0';

    if (strcasecmp(method_str, "GET") != 0) ERR_RET(3)
        else {
            strdecode(path, path);
            if (path[0] != '/') ERR_RET(4)
                else file = &(path[1]);
        }

    if (strlen(file) >= MAXBUFSIZE-1) ERR_RET(4)
        if (strlen(query) >= MAXBUFSIZE-1) ERR_RET(5)
            strcpy(reqP->file, file);
    strcpy(reqP->query, query);

    char *m = strchr(reqP->query, '=') + 1;
    char *filename = strncpy(reqP->query, m, sizeof(reqP->query));

    fprintf(stderr, "filename = %s\n", filename);
    fprintf(stderr, "reqP.conn_fd = %d\n", reqP->conn_fd);
    fprintf(stderr, "reqP.status = %d\n", reqP->status);
    fprintf(stderr, "reqP.file = %s\n", reqP->file);
    fprintf(stderr, "reqP.query = %s\n", reqP->query);
    fprintf(stderr, "reqP.host = %s\n", reqP->host);
    fprintf(stderr, "reqP.buf = %s\n", reqP->buf);
    fprintf(stderr, "reqP.buf_len = %zu\n", reqP->buf_len);
    fprintf(stderr, "reqP.buf_size = %zu\n", reqP->buf_size);
    fprintf(stderr, "reqP.buf_idx = %zu\n", reqP->buf_idx);
    fprintf(stderr, "=============================================\n");

    // if (query[0] == (char) 0) {
    if (query[0] == 'f') {
        fprintf(stderr, "query[0] = %c\n", query[0]);
        // for file request, read it in buf

        r = stat(filename, &sb);
        // r = stat(reqP->file, &sb);
        if (r < 0) ERR_RET(6)
            fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
        // fd = open(reqP->file, O_RDONLY);
        if (fd < 0) ERR_RET(7)
            reqP->buf_len = 0;

        buflen = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\015\012Server: SP TOY\015\012");
        add_to_buf(reqP, buf, buflen);
        now = time((time_t*) 0);
        (void) strftime(timebuf, sizeof(timebuf), "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", gmtime(&now));
        buflen = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Date: %s\015\012", timebuf);
        add_to_buf(reqP, buf, buflen);
        buflen = snprintf(
                          buf, sizeof(buf), "Content-Length: %lld\015\012", (int64_t) sb.st_size);
        add_to_buf(reqP, buf, buflen);
        buflen = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "Connection: close\015\012\015\012");
        add_to_buf(reqP, buf, buflen);

        ptr = mmap(0, (size_t) sb.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
        if (ptr == (void*) -1) ERR_RET(8)
            add_to_buf(reqP, ptr, sb.st_size);
        (void) munmap(ptr, sb.st_size);
        close(fd);
        // printf("%s\n", reqP->buf);
        // fflush(stdout);
        reqP->buf_idx = 0; // writing from offset 0
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void add_to_buf(http_request *reqP, char* str, size_t len) {
    char** bufP = &(reqP->buf);
    size_t* bufsizeP = &(reqP->buf_size);
    size_t* buflenP = &(reqP->buf_len);

    if (*bufsizeP == 0) {
        *bufsizeP = len + 500;
        *buflenP = 0;
        *bufP = (char*) e_malloc(*bufsizeP);
    } else if (*buflenP + len >= *bufsizeP) {
        *bufsizeP = *buflenP + len + 500;
        *bufP = (char*) e_realloc((void*) *bufP, *bufsizeP);
    }
    (void) memmove(&((*bufP)[*buflenP]), str, len);
    *buflenP += len;
    (*bufP)[*buflenP] = '\0';
}

static char* get_request_line(http_request *reqP) {
    int begin;
    char c;

    char *bufP = reqP->buf;
    int buf_len = reqP->buf_len;

    for (begin = reqP->buf_idx ; reqP->buf_idx < buf_len; ++reqP->buf_idx) {
        c = bufP[reqP->buf_idx];
        if (c == '\012' || c == '\015') {
            bufP[reqP->buf_idx] = '\0';
            ++reqP->buf_idx;
            if (c == '\015' && reqP->buf_idx < buf_len &&
                bufP[reqP->buf_idx] == '\012') {
                bufP[reqP->buf_idx] = '\0';
                ++reqP->buf_idx;
            }

            fprintf(stderr, "bufP = %s\n", bufP);
            fprintf(stderr, "=============================================\n");
            return &(bufP[begin]);
        }
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "http request format error\n");
    exit(1);
}

static void init_http_server(http_server *svrP, unsigned short port) {
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    int tmp;

    gethostname(svrP->hostname, sizeof(svrP->hostname));
    svrP->port = port;

    svrP->listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (svrP->listen_fd < 0) ERR_EXIT("socket")

        bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    tmp = 1;
    if (setsockopt(svrP->listen_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void*) &tmp, sizeof(tmp)) < 0) ERR_EXIT ("setsockopt ")
        if (bind(svrP->listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0) ERR_EXIT("bind")
            if (listen(svrP->listen_fd, 1024) < 0) ERR_EXIT("listen")
                }

// Set NDELAY mode on a socket.
static void set_ndelay(int fd) {
    int flags, newflags;

    flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flags != -1) {
        newflags = flags | (int) O_NDELAY; // nonblocking mode
        if (newflags != flags)
            (void) fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, newflags);
    }
}

static void strdecode(char* to, char* from) {
    for (; *from != '\0'; ++to, ++from) {
        if (from[0] == '%' && isxdigit(from[1]) && isxdigit(from[2])) {
            *to = hexit(from[1]) * 16 + hexit(from[2]);
            from += 2;
        } else {
            *to = *from;
        }
    }
    *to = '\0';
}

static int hexit(char c) {
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        return c - '0';
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
        return c - 'a' + 10;
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
        return c - 'A' + 10;
    return 0;           // shouldn't happen
}

static void* e_malloc(size_t size) {
    void* ptr;

    ptr = malloc(size);
    if (ptr == (void*) 0) {
        (void) fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return ptr;
}

static void* e_realloc(void* optr, size_t size) {
    void* ptr;

    ptr = realloc(optr, size);
    if (ptr == (void*) 0) {
        (void) fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

And here is the file_reader.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define ERR_EXIT(a) { perror(a); exit(1); }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char c;
    char buf[1024];
    int i = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "filename = %s\n", argv[1]);

    if (fp == NULL) 
        ERR_EXIT("ERROR open!\n")
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        buf[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    buf[i] = '\0';
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, sizeof(buf));
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Obviously `select` believes there is an invalid fd in `readfs`. But you haven't even provided the code that sets `master` which makes it very difficult to diagnose the issue. Please provide an MCVE.

Comment: Are there any compilation warnings?  If so, fix them before reporting any problem.  Are you using enough warnings to be confident?  If you use GCC, you should use at least `-Werror -Wall`; the `-Werror` will stop you ignoring warnings.  You should probably add `-Wextra`; personally, I use more warnings than that.

Comment: Thx everyone!I just figured out what's wrong, I forgot to close and FD_CLR after correctly handle_read, this cause the Bad file descriptor in select function.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing multiple connected clients in the same `requestP` slot, because you are using the **listening socket descriptor** as the array index after calling `accept()`.  That will work if there is only ever 1 client connected at a time, otherwise you will be trashing that slot when multiple clients are connected at a time.

However, your reading/writing code is using the **client socket descriptor** as the array index.  Since the client socket descriptors are different values than the listening socket descriptor, you need to change `requestP[i]` to `requestP[conn_fd]` when preparing a newly `accept()`'ed client.

This also assumes that `requestP` is a fixed-length array and the various socket descriptors never exceed the bounds of the array when used as indexes.

You are also not re-calculating `maxfd` whenever you remove a socket descriptor from the `master` list.  That could also be contributing to your error.

You are also not handling the case where `write()` returns a blocking error on a non-blocking socket.  In that case, you need to use the `write_fds` part of `select()` to detect when the socket can accept more data before calling `write()` again.

A better solution would be to change `requestP` into a dynamic array or linked list, and stop using socket descriptors as array indexes altogether, eg:

```
typedef struct http_request {
    http_request *next;

    int conn_fd;               // fd to talk with client
    int status;                // not used, error, reading (from client), writing (to client)

    char file[MAXBUFSIZE];     // requested file
    char query[MAXBUFSIZE];    // requested query
    char host[MAXBUFSIZE];     // client host
    char* buf;                 // data sent by/to client
    size_t buf_len;            // bytes used by buf
    size_t buf_size;           // bytes allocated for buf
    size_t buf_idx;            // offset for reading and writing
} http_request;

http_request *requests_head = NULL;
http_request *requests_tail = NULL;

while (1) {                             /* Main loop */
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    FD_ZERO(&write_fds);

    FD_SET(server.listen_fd, &read_fds);
    int maxfd = server.listen_fd;

    http_request *request = requests_head;
    while (request) {
        FD_SET(request->conn_fd, &read_fds);
        if (request->status == WRITING} {
            FD_SET(request->conn_fd, &write_fds);
        }
        maxfd = max(request->conn_fd, maxfd);
        request = request->next;
    }

    if (select(maxfd+1, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL, NULL) < 0)
        ERR_EXIT("select")
    printf("server select() is OK!\n");

    if (FD_ISSET(server.listen_fd, &read_fds)) {
        clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
        conn_fd = accept(server.listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, (socklen_t *) &clilen);
        if (conn_fd < 0) {
            if ((errno != EINTR) && (errno != EAGAIN)) { // try again later
                if (errno != ENFILE) {
                    ERR_EXIT("accept")
                }
                fprintf(stderr, "out of file descriptor table ... (maxconn %d)\n", maxfd);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            request = (http_request*) malloc(sizeof(http_request));
            if (!request) {
                // error handling ...
                close(conn_fd);
            }
            else
            {
                memset(request, 0, sizeof(http_request));

                request->conn_fd = conn_fd;
                request->status = READING;
                strcpy(request->host, inet_ntoa(cliaddr.sin_addr));
                set_ndelay(conn_fd);

                fprintf(stderr, "getting a new request... fd %d from %s\n", conn_fd, request->host);

                if (!requests_head) requests_head = request;
                if (requests_tail) requests_tail->next = request;
                requests_tail = request;
            }
        }
    }

    request = requests_head;
    http_request *next, *prev = NULL;
    while (request) {
        if (FD_ISSET(request->conn_fd, &read_fds)) {
            // Handle data from a client 
            if (request->state != READING) {
                char recv[1024];
                if (read(request->conn_fd, recv, sizeof(recv)) <= 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "error on fd %d, code %d\n", request->conn_fd, err);
                    close(request->conn_fd);
                    free_request(request);

                    next = request->next;
                    if (request == requests_head) requests_head = next;
                    if (request == requests_tail) requests_tail = prev;
                    if (prev) prev->next = next;
                    free(request);

                    request = next;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "reading from conn_fd %d\n", request->conn_fd);
                ret = read_header_and_file(request, &err);
                if (ret < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "error on fd %d, code %d\n", request->conn_fd, err);
                    close(request->conn_fd);
                    free_request(request);

                    next = request->next;
                    if (request == requests_head) requests_head = next;
                    if (request == requests_tail) requests_tail = prev;
                    if (prev) prev->next = next;
                    free(request);

                    request = next;
                    continue;
                }

                if (ret == 0) {
                    request->status = WRITING;
                    FD_SET(request->conn_fd, &write_fds);
                }
            }
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(request->conn_fd, &write_fds)) {
            // Handle data to a client 
            if (request->buf_idx < request->buf_len) {
                fprintf(stderr, "writing (buf %s, idx %d) %d bytes to request fd %d\n", request->buf, (int) request->buf_idx, (int) request->buf_len, request->conn_fd);
                nwritten = write(request->conn_fd, &request->buf[request->buf_idx], request->buf_len - request->buf_idx);
                if (nwritten < 0) {
                    if ((errno != EINTR) && (errno != EAGAIN)) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "error on fd %d, code %d\n", request->conn_fd, errno);
                        close(request->conn_fd);
                        free_request(request);

                        next = request->next;
                        if (request == requests_head) requests_head = next;
                        if (request == requests_tail) requests_tail = prev;
                        if (prev) prev->next = next;
                        free(request);

                        request = next;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    request->buf_idx += nwritten;
                }
            }

            if (request->buf_idx == request->buf_len) {
                fprintf(stderr, "complete writing %d bytes on fd %d\n", (int) request->buf_len, request->conn_fd);
                fprintf(stderr, "=============================================\n");

                int fd[2];
                if (pipe(fd) == -1)
                    ERR_EXIT("pipe")

                pid_t pid;
                if ((pid = fork()) < 0) 
                    ERR_EXIT("fork")

                else if (pid == 0) {       /* In Child Process */
                    close(fd[0]);
                    dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                    close(fd[1]);

                    execl("file_reader", "./file_reader", request->query, (char *)0);
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unexpect flow of control.\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                else {      /* In Parent Process */
                    close(fd[1]);
                    char recv[1024];
                    read(fd[0], recv, sizeof(recv));
                    printf("The file content is:\n%s\n", recv);
                }

                close(request->conn_fd);
                free_request(request);

                next = request->next;
                if (request == requests_head) requests_head = next;
                if (request == requests_tail) requests_tail = prev;
                if (prev) prev->next = next;
                free(request);

                request = next;
                continue;
            }
        }

        request = request->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you close an FD that is in the `readFDS` or `writeFDs` you need to remove it from there.

Comment: You don't need to remove it from `readFDS` or `writeFDS` while you are still looping through them. You just need to make sure you don't pass it to subsequent `select()` calls. And the code is already handling that by removing it from the `master` list before calling `select()` again.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I didn't say anything about removing it while still looping through them, although that is certainly how I woud do it. and his code cannot possibly be 'handling that' correctly. The only way he can get this error is by having an invalid FD in the `read/writeFDs`, and the only way that can happen is by either inventing one, which isn't apparent, or continuing to use a closed one.

Comment: See my answer, he is not even managing the `requestP` array and its indexes correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm having trouble understanding what you're talking about. We seem to be in complete agreement but without you realizing it. He is mismanaging his FDs to the extent that he isn't removing a closed FD and so getting EBADF. The only other way to get that is to invent an FD out of whole cloth, and I don't see any evidence for that either in the OP or your answer.